# How to use R function tableby() to get the strata printed as extra columns instead of extra rows, or another way to accomplish the same thing?

Tags: r, statistics, r-markdown

I would like to use the R function tableby() to get the strata printed as extra columns instead of extra rows, or find another way to accomplish the same thing. I show an example with the mockstudy data below. However, my actual dataset has many more variables (both categorical and numeric), so the different format makes much more sense. Plus, I want to show the number of observations in each subcategory (e.g., Treatment Arm A and Male, Treatment Arm A and Female, etc.).

As a short example, I have the following code in an Rmardown file to generate a table with summary statistics using the tableby() function from the arsenal package in R.

---

### title: "Testing tableby() output"
output: html_document
date: "2023-11-29"

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
library(arsenal) # for tableby()
require(knitr)
data(mockstudy) # load data

summary(tableby(sex ~ age + bmi, strata = arm, subset = arm %in% c("A: IFL", "F: FOLFOX"), data = mockstudy))
```

Which generates the following output:

[image: Rmarkdown output showing table]

However, I would like a table arranged in the following way, with the correct N at the top of each column:

[image: Example headers of table I want]

Is there a way to do this with tableby() or another function in another R package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With arsenal and tableby(), I believe your strata argument (`strata=arm`) is the best way to do it.

Instead, I’d recommend looking into something like [tblstrata() in the gtsummary package](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_strata.html); it would give you something that looks like this: [Example from gtsummary documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUobk.png).

Using the same example you gave, the code would be:

```
table_example <-
  mockstudy %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = arm,
    .tbl_fun =
      ~ .x %>%
        tbl_summary(by = sex, missing = "no") %>%
        add_n(),
    .header = "**{strata}**, N = {n}"
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! The tbl_strata() function in the gtsummary package does exactly what I want, and your example was so helpful. I added a little more to your example to get the p-values displayed as well (see below answer for well formatted code).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @emsoap! I added a little more to your example to get the p-values displayed as well (I couldn't figure out how to get the code to post correctly in my comment to you):

```
library(gtsummary) # for tbl_strata()

table_example <-
  mockstudy %>%
  select(age, bmi, sex, arm) %>%
  filter(arm %in% c("A: IFL", "F: FOLFOX")) %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = arm,
    .tbl_fun =
      ~ .x %>%
        tbl_summary(by = sex, missing = "no") %>%
        add_n() %>%
      add_p(test= everything() ~ 'aov'),
    .header = "**{strata}**, N = {n}"
  )

table_example
```